# How to check if column is integer in conditional split component in ssis?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have the following SSIS package:

[image]

In my package, flat file source data feeds into a conditional split component.  One of the columns is `AccountNo`.
That column in the flat file source output datatype is:  `string [DT_STR]`.

I want to check in the Constraint Check component if `AccountNo` is an integer.  For example, maybe that column in the flat file source is this:

```
12355ss2rt3
```

and that input is not an integer.  I want to pass a valid integer number to the constraint check output.   In the constraint check component, I have this:

[image]

this expression uses Type Cast Group and `(DT_I8)`  condition, but I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use derived column to do that.

In my example, the input is:

```
AccountNo
123
1234
123f
1e23
```

**Step 1: Try to cast string to integer**

Just use derived column, try to cast to I8

`(DT_I8)AccountNo`

**Step 2: Config error out, to catch error row**

The success casting rows will go to the nomarl flow, the value that can not cast to I8 will be redirect to the error flow.
The general data flow is like this (view screenshot):
[Data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffUeL.png)

To get the error value, you just drap and drop the red arrow from the driver column.

Now the red flow is contain the value that can not cast to integer
the blue flow is flow with value successful casting.

view following screenshot for detail:

[Screenshot - Step 2 Config error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh3YG.png)

**Step 3: process uncast value with the way you want**

note that the output of error flow will give you 2 valuable columns are:

- [ErrorCode]
- [ErrorColumn]

Let use these column to make sure the error from "cast to integer fail".

You can refer to msdn document to lookup for `ErrorCode`.

Base on `ErrorColumn`, you can make sure the error come from column `AccountNo` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Directly using conditional split you will not able to do this.

use  derived column  /Script component to check if data is numeric or not

create an derived  column isNumeric

Expression : (DT_I4)AccountNo == (DT_I4)AccountNo ? 1 : 0

now use this in conditional split .