# SSIS Flat File Destination with a Flat File Source

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

I have a flat file source which has rows given as :

```
ID,NAME,EMAIL_ADDRESS,REGISTRATION_DATE
1a,Anna,HEDMANITE1@ICLOUD.COM,11/26/2019 
2b,Mary,JIMMYO42@ICLOUD.COM,11/26/2019 
3c,Sam,BROOKESTANFILL@YAHOO.COM,11/26/2019 
1,Anna,T_CACIENNE@YAHOO.COM,11/26/2019 
1,Anna,JMMILLE1@YAHOO.COM,11/26/2019 
1,Anna,B.MILLER2@CES95.ORG,11/26/2019 
1,Anna,RAMIREZANDRW@YAHOO.COM,11/26/2019 
1,Anna,ARLENE.GARCIA0626@GMAIL.COM,11/26/2019
```

As you can see the first 3 rows are error rows, with ID values as 1a,2b and 3c.
I placed a Flat File Destination (a notepad text folder) from the Flat File Source to redirect the errors to that flat file,but when I run the code, the errors are not shown in the Flat File Destination and in the non-error output,the error rows are not present. How do I place the errors in a flat file destination ?

Comment: I think we'd need to see how you have the Error Output tab on your non-error destination configured.

Comment: Check out this answer (not mine) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450379/how-to-check-if-column-is-integer-in-conditional-split-component-in-ssis